# Understanding chemical reactions

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I just got in 10th grade and the first chapter in Chemistry in our school curriculum is *Chemical Reactions and Equations*

The chapter is littered with a **lot** of chemical reactions and their equations and most of the teachers I consult say that there is no alternative to revising them but I **hate** to blindly memorize stuff without knowing why it happens in that manner and not in some other way.

Is it really true that there is no other way than to **memorize** the equations?

If there is an alternative, please let me know.

And how can I predict the products of a chemical reaction if its reactants are given. Is it done by understanding the types of chemical reactions.

One of my teachers said that it could be done like this : If you're given two elements as reactants and you know that they will react, then you know that it is a combination reaction, you can figure out the chemical formula of the compound that those two elements will form on combination and then balance the equation. This works for simple reactions like *Na + Cl $\longrightarrow$ NaCl* or for some simple decomposition, displacement or double displacement reactions but what about complex reactions like this :

$2 Pb(NO_ 2)_3$ (s) $\longrightarrow$ $2PbO$ (s) + $4NO_2$ (g) + $O_2$ (g)

I can quite easily visualize a combination reaction as two elements sharing or losing or gaining electrons and combining to form a compound, but how do I visualize these types of reactions

I'm sorry if you find this question silly...

All answers are welcome

Thanks

Comment: Nobody will require that you memorize the equation of the decomposition of $\ce{Pb(NO_3)2}$. It is an example of a difficult reaction in the 10th grade. What a teacher can ask is that you find the stoichiometric coefficients in front of the formula. I mean you should find that 2 $\ce{Pb(NO_3)2}$ (and not 1) are required to produce the reaction. And the teacher will tell you that $\ce{PbO}$, $\ce{NO_2}$, and $\ce{O_2}$ are produced. Your job would be to find the coefficient 2, 4 and 1.

Comment: Thanks for the edit, first of all, but apparently, in India, that's not the type of questions that are asked in exams. Our teacher gave us an assignment of this chapter and the first question itself happened to be : Write a balanced  chemical reaction describing the thermal decomposition of lead nitrate...

Comment: Sindhu. I am surprised of your information. Because, without some supplementary information, nobody can predict tant lead nitrate behave this way. You might as well have proposed an equation like : $\ce{Pb(NO_3)2}$ -> $\ce{PbO_2}$ + $\ce{N_2O_4}$. This last equation is not stupid. Nobody can exclude it without any other information.

Comment: And in the next chapter : *Acids, Bases and Salts*, we have to memorize stuff about every single acid, base and salt given in the book. We have to learn their properties, their reaction with some elements, their formation and what not.

Comment: This all is basically memorizing, right? And as I mentioned, I hate to **memorize blindly**, it ruins all the fun there is in the subject

Comment: @Maurice In India, the first thing they'll teach you is : Study for marks. Concepts are valued extremely extremely little in Indian education. If someone tries to understand rather than learn in Inorganic Chemistry, they mostly fail because they don't get any resources to help them for that. Quoting John von Neumann, my role model ***There is no sense in being precise if you don't know what you're talking about.***
 I'd rather fail than learn these reactions without knowing what causes them

Comment: @Maurice what do you suggest?

Comment: Acid-base reactions are systematic. You can easily guess or rediscover how they will react. It is like a machinery that always works with all acids and all bases. No problem ! This not the case of the decomposition of lead nitrate, which produces $\ce{PbO, NO_2 , O_2}$. This cannot be derived by reasoning. For example, with another nitrate, the reaction proceeds another way. With $\ce{ KNO_3}$ for example, it produces $\ce{KNO_2 + O_2}$. And this is impossible to guess, or to deduce in advance. Fortunately the acid-base chapter is absolutely logic.

Comment: @Maurice Thank You. So, some chemical reactions are to be memorized and their products were discovered by scientists just by experiments, right? By the way, you were really helpful. :)